# Laravel image got corrupted while decoding from base64 and storing to local storage

Tags: php, laravel, image, file-upload, base64

```
$imgData = base64_decode($validatedData['img']);
$uniqueFilename = hash('sha256', time() . $imgData) . '.jpg';
Storage::disk('public')->put('products/' . $uniqueFilename, $imgData);
```

I have used this code to store an image in local storage. The file is successfully stored, but when I try to open it, it appears to be corrupted. I have tried various solutions but to no avail. Can someone please guide me on how to fix this issue?

Comment: This line `$uniqueFilename = hash('sha256', time() . $imgData) . '.jpg';` <<<=== is weird. Your `$imgData` is your 'img' from validatedData. That 'img' is a base_64 encoded string. Try to find the actual filename in your $validatedData. Next, catch your 'img' variable, write it to a file, temporarily. Then manually base64_decode it. Write that to a .jpg file. Now, is the file readable? That might mean that the **posted** data is corrupted. Does it come from an Api?

Comment: by using this line i am generating the unique filename using a combination of the current time and the image data.

yes data is coming from API from react client side.

Comment: using the hash() function with sha256 provides a unique identifier for the image file.

As for your suggestion, I have already decoded the base64-encoded image data and stored it in a file using the put() method of the Storage facade, which has been successful. The issue is with the image being corrupted after being stored.

The data comes from a form submission and is validated before being processed. The image data is passed as a base64-encoded string and is decoded before being stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code to decode any base64 file like image, pdf, mp3, etc. without knowing and having actual file details inside base64 encoded string.

```
$encodedString = explode(',', $base64String, 2);
$decodedImage = str_replace(' ', '+', $encodedString[1]);

$decodedImage = base64_decode($decodedImage);
$mime_type = finfo_buffer(finfo_open(), $decodedImage, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$extension = $this->mime2ext($mime_type);

$imageName = Str::random().'.'.$extension;
Storage::disk('upload')->put($imageName, $decodedImage);
return $imageName;
```

add below function to the same class or use trait for identifying file format, you can also add more mime types to this array if you are dealing with any other file formats as well.

```
public function mime2ext($mime)
{
    $all_mimes = '{
    "png":["image\/png","image\/x-png"],
    "bmp":["image\/bmp","image\/x-bmp","image\/x-bitmap","image\/x-xbitmap","image\/x-win-bitmap","image\/x-windows-bmp","image\/ms-bmp","image\/x-ms-bmp","application\/bmp","application\/x-bmp","application\/x-win-bitmap"],
    "gif":["image\/gif"],
    "jpeg":["image\/jpeg","image\/pjpeg", "image\/x-citrix-jpeg"]
    }';

    $all_mimes = json_decode($all_mimes,true);
    foreach ($all_mimes as $key => $value) {
        if(array_search($mime,$value) !== false) return $key;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro you have done the job :) JazzakALLAH